# Template argument deduction fails

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use tags and `enable_if` to enforce constraints on template parameters. Here is the code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Type>
struct tag {}; 

struct Atag {}; 
struct Btag {};

template<typename Type, typename Tag>
struct tag_enabled
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_same
        <
            typename tag<Type>::type, 
            Tag 
        >::value, 
        "Error: Type is not tagged with Tag."
    ); 

    typedef typename std::enable_if
    <
        std::is_same
        <
            typename tag<Type>::type, 
            Tag 
        >::value, 
        Type
    >::type type; 
};

template<typename A>
typename tag_enabled<A, Atag>::type
worker(
   typename tag_enabled<A, Atag>::type const & a
)
{
    A result; 

    std::cout << "Atag -> Atag" << std::endl;

    return result; 
}

template<typename A, typename B>
typename tag_enabled<A, Atag>::type
worker(
    typename tag_enabled<B, Btag>::type const & b
)
{
    A result; 

    std::cout << "Btag -> Atag" << std::endl;

    return result; 
}


template<typename A, typename ... Args>
A caller(Args ... args)
{
    return worker<A>(args ...);
}

struct test_a {}; 
struct test_b {}; 

template<>
struct tag<test_a>
{
    typedef Atag type; 
};

template<>
struct tag<test_b>
{
    typedef Btag type;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    // caller int(int)
    test_a ta1; 
    test_b tb1; 

    auto ta2 = caller<test_a>(ta1); 

    // Why does this fail?  
    auto ta3 = caller<test_a>(tb1);

    return 0;
}
```

And it results with the following errors:

```
test-template.cpp: In instantiation of ‘A caller(Args ...) [with A = test_a; Args = {test_b}]’:
test-template.cpp:90:34:   required from here
test-template.cpp:63:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘worker(test_b&)’
     return worker<A>(args ...);
                              ^
test-template.cpp:63:30: note: candidates are:
test-template.cpp:35:1: note: template<class A> typename tag_enabled<A, Atag>::type worker(const typename tag_enabled<A, Atag>::type&)
 worker(
 ^
test-template.cpp:35:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test-template.cpp:63:30: note:   cannot convert ‘args#0’ (type ‘test_b’) to type ‘const type& {aka const test_a&}’
     return worker<A>(args ...);
                              ^
test-template.cpp:48:1: note: template<class A, class B> typename tag_enabled<A, Atag>::type worker(const typename tag_enabled<B, Btag>::type&)
 worker(
 ^
test-template.cpp:48:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test-template.cpp:63:30: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘B’
     return worker<A>(args ...);
```

All errors but the last one are expected and welcomed. The `tag_enabled` should make sure that function templates do not get instantiated, based on the template parameter tags. This error for example:

```
test-template.cpp:35:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    test-template.cpp:63:30: note:   cannot convert ‘args#0’ (type ‘test_b’) to type ‘const type& {aka const test_a&}’
         return worker<A>(args ...);
```

is great because I want the deduction to fail for that function, since it's supposed to perform the mapping `Atag -> Atag` and not `Btag -> Atag`. SFINAE would (I hope so at least) just drop this function candidate, if the two-parameter function template would work. This is the error I'm concerned with, why is the template argument deduction failing here:

```
test-template.cpp:48:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test-template.cpp:63:30: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘B’
     return worker<A>(args ...);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compiler can deduce a type template argument, `A` or `B`, and a non-type template argument, `N`, from a template function argument with a type composed of the following constructs ([Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) 23.5.2, iso 14.8.2.1):

```
A
const A
volatile A
A*
A&
A[constant_expression]
type[N]
class_template<A>
class_template<N>
B<A>
A<N>
A<>
A type::*
A A::*
type A::*
A (*)(args)
type (A::*)(args)
A (type::*)(args)
type (type::*)(args_AN)
A (A::*)(args_AN)
type (A::*)(args_AN)
A (type::*)(args_AN)
type (*)(args_AN)
```

where `args` is a parameter list that does not allow deduction, and `args_AN` is a parameter list from which an `A` or an `N` can be determined by recursive application of the above rules. If not all parameters can be deduced in this way, a call is ambiguous.

Your construct

```
typename tag_enabled<B, Btag>::type const &
```

does not have one of the above forms, so `B` cannot be deduced from

```
template<typename A, typename B>
typename tag_enabled<A, Atag>::type
worker(typename tag_enabled<B, Btag>::type const & b)
```

`B` has to be specified explicitly, exactly as is the case for [std::forward](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). Unfortunately, this is quite inconvenient. A couple of ways to make it convenient while allowing deduction would be

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename = typename std::enable_if <...> >
typename tag_enabled<A, Atag>::type
worker(B const& b)
```

or

```
template<typename A, typename B>
typename tag_enabled<A, Atag, B, Btag>::type
worker(B const& b)
```

Either way, you would have to change your design a little.

Comment: Doesn't the tag_enabled actually result with `B const &` when `B` is tagged with `Btag` and then the external `const` qualifier is stripped away by ADL, resulting in `B&` which is in the table you posted in the answer?

Comment: @tmaric I does, but the compiler cannot *deduce* `B` within `typename tag_enabled<B, Btag>::type` because this is not one of the above forms. If `B` were *given*, then yes, the compiler would result in `B const &` as you say.

Comment: @tmaric Think about this another way: I could write `tag_enabled` in a way that `typename tag_enabled<B, Btag>::type` would result in `X` *whatever* `B` is. Then, given `X`, what would `B` be? It's a matter of *inverting* a (type) function: the function has to invertible. The compiler doesn't know.

Comment: thanks! I'm reading the templates book, and it seems that the reason for this is that the argument deduction is a top to bottom approach :"matching process proceeds from the top-level construct and recurses through the composing elements" ...